# Edit a nested resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the following code segment

```
.comment
    %p= comment.comment
    %p= comment.user.email

    = link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(comment.post, comment) 
    = link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure"'}
```

why do both **Edit** and **Delete** take in **comment.post** as a parameter? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It require **comment.post** because you have made nested routes, check your routes.rb file where you have define routes as below:

```
 resources :posts  do
   resources :comments
 end
```

and your routes is for EDIT and DELETE is

```
edit_post_comment GET  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit    

DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)  comments#destroy
```

That's why you always need to pass comment.post as a parameter.

If you don't want comment.post as parameter you can change your routes as:

```
resources :posts
resources :comments
```

OR if you don,t want to pass comment.id in any particular action do your routes as

```
resources :posts  do
  resources :comments, :except => [:delete]
end

resources :comments, :only => [:delete]
```

**NOTE:** I am assuming that you don't want comment.post parameter for :delete action

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! Sorry for not clarifying the question, but I was trying to figure out why is it comment.post and not post.comment. As comments are nested inside posts, I assumed that it was post.comment, and couldn't figure out why it was wrong until much googling later. Is there a reason, or is it simply convention?

Comment: If you check  routes (i.e. nested routes) you need to have both comment and post, so you have to pass 'comment.post' because you don't have post object for your view.

Answer (score 0):

Comment is a nested resource here which means comments belongs to a post. 
Because rails routes are defined in a **RESTFUL** Way.

If you see in the RESTful way, all the CRUD operations in comment resource require post resource id, since comment is associated with post.

Not only the 'Edit' and 'Delete' operation requires parent resource id, All the CRUD operation requires it.

Have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) at Nested resource section.